# HTML Icon overflow at scrolling

Tags: html, css, icons, scrollbar

I can't figure out why the Icons are overlapping when I'm scrolling. I've already used `overflow: hidden` and tried various methods of hiding it. E.g with different `divs` that should hide one Icon.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="bar">
      <div class="flex-item">ID</div>
      <div class="flex-item">Name</div>
      <div class="flex-item">Erfassung</div>
      <div class="flex-item">Frist</div>
      <div class="flex-item"><a href="logout.php"><img src="icons/logout_FILL0_wght400_GRAD0_opsz48.svg"></a></div>
   </div>
   <div class="data">
      <?php 
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo '<div class="dataRow" id="stat' . $row['Status'] . '">';
      echo    '<div class="flex-item">' . $row['ID'] . '</div>';
      echo    '<div class="flex-item">' . $row['Vorname'] . " " . $row['Nachname'] . '</div>';
      echo    '<div class="flex-item">' . $row['Erfassung'] . '</div>';
      echo    '<div class="flex-item">' . $row['Frist'] . '</div>';
      echo    '<div class="flex-item">' . '<a href="details.php?ID=' . $row['ID'] . '"><img src="icons/arrow_forward_ios_FILL0_wght400_GRAD0_opsz48.svg" overflow="hidden"></a>' . '</div>';
      echo '</div>';
      }
      ?>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.bar {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    font-weight: bold;
    top: 0;
    position: sticky;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    background-color: #232323;
    padding-block: 0.25em;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

img {
    width: 2.15em;
    max-width: 2.15em;
    filter: invert(100%);
}

.data {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.dataRow {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-bottom: 0.25em;
}

#stat1 {
    background-color: #c0161a;
}

#stat2 {
    background-color: #c4c41b;
}

#stat3 {
    background-color: #4cbb2d;
}

.flex-item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(1) {
    flex: 1;
    background-color: #373737;
    margin-right: 0.25em;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(2) {
    flex: 5;
    background-color: #373737;
    margin-right: 0.25em;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(3) {
    flex: 2;
    background-color: #373737;
    margin-right: 0.25em;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(4) {
    flex: 2;
    background-color: #373737;
    margin-right: 0.25em;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(5) {
    flex: 0.5;
    background-color: #373737;
}
```

How can I prevent the overlapping?
The idea is that when the user is scrolling, the bar sticks to the top and nothing is overlapping. So the bar is always on top. Including the Icon.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1FUR.gif)

Comment: Can you show us a gif of the behaviour?

Comment: Here you go: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1FUR.gif

Comment: basically I would say put a margin-top on data, value equal of bar height. I tried to reproduce but I don't have the data, so I'm answering only regarding your example. You can also put the bar in position fixed

Comment: That's not my Problem. If you look closely, you see in the GIF that the Icon on the top right is clipping. I'm unable to fix that.

Comment: Did you try to use z-index? .container z-index:2 / .bar z-index:2 / .data z-index:1

Comment: PS: Adding overflow:hidden inside the img is not doing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:** The sticky header is on the same z-index level as the content, which causes the header and content to overlap.

**Solution:** Tell the browser that the sticky header should be on top of the data, by using **z-index**. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).

**CSS:**

```css
.container{
   z-index:2;
}
.bar{
   z-index:2;
}
.data{
   z-index:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you try to use flex grid? it can maybe solve the problem.